# How to find out IntentReceiverLeaked source on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-leaks, android-memory

I am developing an Android App and I use `Eclipse` + `MAT` to develop and inspect memory usage/leaks.

I check the unfiltered (full) `LogCat` output and there is nothing related to "IntentReceiverLeaked" but when I inspect `Heap Dump`, I see that `android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked` object is there and it increments when I run the app and exit it with back button and reopen it again. (For sure, back button does not kill the app as expected, I just noted that to tell you how `IntentReceiverLeaked` object increments.)

It is not possible for me to detect the leak manually by commenting out some of the code to see where it is, as the source is large and complex.

It is almost obvious that an exception is being thrown but I am probably suppressing it with a zero-output catch block.

Is there anyway to catch this `IntentReceiverLeaked` source?

**update**

I also checked receiver objects and these are the only ones:

[image]

**update2**

I do not use inner classes for creating a BroadcastReceiver.